# Best approach to developing a cross-browser JavaScript widget that populates from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, cross-browser

I'm currently researching the best way to approach building a JavaScript widget someone can embed on their site, which would retrieve and display information from an external MySQL database.

The gist of the widget would mimic the needs/functionality of Twitter's widget (http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets), where it uses some combination of JavaScript, PHP and/or AJAX and retrieves information from a MySQL database with secure (or at least somewhat safe) cross-browser access. Does anyone have thoughts or ideas on the best and most reliable way to approach something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great guide to building a cross-domain widget: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

The hard part is the Javascript side; the server side can be written in PHP, or Python, or Ruby or whatever. Your google search should include the term "javascript widget" to get more articles like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple. Encapsulate your widget entirely in a JS file if possible (minus images) and use AJAX for calling a REST or SOAP (probably want to stick to REST) webservice for any data access you need.

Comment: Thanks Kris. Any tips on where to start (i.e. tutorials or the right terms to Google)?

Comment: Quick update: After spending a few hours scouring the web, I've found bits and pieces of solutions, but nothing that fits what I'm looking to do. If anyone has a good resource for building a PHP web service that is consumed by a JS widget (cross-browser), please share!

Comment: After a few days of research I haven't found anything that would make this 'simple.' In fact, I've found no proof that it can be done securely either. Any one else have any tips or direction?

Comment: I do not know enough PHP to offer guidance as to how to create a webservice with it. However, it would be safe as you're not directly connecting to a database but, instead, calling a simple web page (which webservices are, basically), grabbing the data and displaying it. Now, if you wanted to SAVE or MODIFY data via the webservice; that's going to require additional security but you'd still want to go through a webservice; you'd just have to create some sort of authentication scheme.

Answer (score 0):

IFRAME, just use a iframe. you have

- native sandbox
- control over your environment
- no updating your widget for your users if there is a new browser. You just update your code in your iframe.
- Everyone uses this method ( Google+, Youtube, Facebook, Twitter )

its a win win situation.